# Mysql Query Select Statement Help Needed

Tags: mysql

I have a query of mysql where i fetch how much has the total sale gone ,

but it shows `previous dates [Date] => 2014-01-22`   `[TotalSales] => 7` ,

It shows this way ,  how can i make it , so that it shows todays date and shows the sale up till now

```
 SELECT DATE(order_time) AS Date, SUM(Quantity) AS TotalSales
 FROM ss_orders,ss_ordered_carts
 GROUP BY date;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then add a where clause, comparing your order_time with today's date.
like this:

```
SELECT DATE(order_time) AS Date, SUM(Quantity) AS TotalSales
        FROM ss_orders,ss_ordered_carts
        WHERE DATE(order_time) = DATE(NOW())
         group by date;
```